# VBA lookup value from column and if matches on other workbook, copy corresponding cell value into other workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Excel workbooks with the same name but one is opened via a url:

Workbook 54.xlsm

```
Column A       Column B      Column C
--------------------------------------    
01/12/2016     12345         Notes
03/12/2016     23456         Notes
01/12/2016     78643         Notes
03/12/2016     12345         Notes
```

Workbook 54.xlsm

```
Column A       Column B      Column C
-------------------------------------    
01/12/2016     12345         
03/12/2016     23456         
01/12/2016     78643         
03/12/2016     12345
```

I am trying to open the latest version of Workbook 54 online and essentially want to be able to copy the notes out of column C from the 1st (older) version of Workbook 54 and paste these into the latest version of workbook 54 where the number in column B matches and where the date in column a matches.

Here's my code so far, for some reason what I've put together doesn't seem to do anything.

```
'Download File - Check URL
Sub File()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = Now

    Const sURL As String = "https://intranet-uk.lidl.net/info-centre/docsdb/Document%20Database/08.%20Buying/8.3%20Food%20Specials/Current%20Information/Food%20Specials%20and%20Seasonal%20Depot%20Memos/"

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sURL & "Food%20Specials%20Rolling%20Depot%20Memo%2045%20-%2052.xlsm")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sURL & "Food%20Specials%20Rolling%20Depot%20Memo%2046%20-%2001.xlsm")
    End If

    Set GetCFWorkbook = wb



    Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("Food Specials Rolling Depot Memo 46 - 01.xlsm")
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w1 = Workbooks(LookupWB).Sheets("Sheet1")

    i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("J6:J" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, -3).Value
        End If
    Next

    i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("J6:J" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `Set w1 = Workbooks(LookupWB).Sheets("Sheet1")` --> `Set w1 = LookupWB.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: I didn't think there was any way possible to have 2 workbooks open with the exact same name, regardless of where they come from. Regardless, have you stepped through the code with the locals window visible and watched what's happening at each step to determine where the code stops doing what you expect?

Comment: ^^ What A.S.H and Michael both said...